# How to use a controller variable the in selected field for in collection_select in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have this array variable in my controller: `@estudiantes_seleccionados = @clase.estudiantes`

Specifically, in:

```rb
def set_clase
  @clase = Clase.find(params[:id])
  @estudiantes_seleccionados = @clase.estudiantes
end
```

How do I use it (@estudiantes_seleccionados) in the `selected:` field in a `collection_select` in the view as to preselect the multiple values in the variable when loading the dropdown ?

`<%= collection_select(:estudiantes, :id, Estudiante.all, :id, :id_campus, {selected:  @estudiantes_seleccionados}, {class: 'form-control', multiple: 'true'}) %>`

The problem seems to be `multiple: 'true'`. When I delete it, only one of the values of @estudiantes_seleccionados gets preselected in the dropdown, but when it is present, none of the values in  the array appears.

So, how do I have all the values in `@estudiantes_seleccionados` the appear as preselected in the dropdown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```rb
<%= collection_select(:estudiantes, :id, Estudiante.all, :id, :id_campus, {selected: @estudiantes_seleccionados.map(&:id)}, {class: 'form-control', multiple: 'true'}) %>
```